# Cannot run rspec anymore

Tags: ruby, linux, rspec

I had ruby 2.0 with rspec 3.0. I uninstalled all rspec 3.0 gems and replaced them with 2.0. I did this to get rid of deprecation warnings. Now, my specs are not working. I am getting the error below. What does the error tell me and how do i fix it ? None of the stack overflow posts on this were helpful.

```
/zombie/spec/spec_helper.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions=' for #<RSpec::Matchers::Configuration:0x00000001a73928> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/lsusr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:398:in `expect_with'
    from /home/lsusr/Code/Rspec/zombie/spec/spec_helper.rb:21:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/lsusr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core.rb:92:in `configure'
    from /home/lsusr/Code/Rspec/zombie/spec/spec_helper.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/lsusr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/lsusr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/lsusr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:434:in `block in requires='
    from /home/lsusr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:434:in `map'
    from /home/lsusr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:434:in `requires='
    from /home/lsusr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:20:in `block in configure'
    from /home/lsusr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:19:in `each'
    from /home/lsusr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:19:in `configure'
    from /home/lsusr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:21:in `run'
    from /home/lsusr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /home/lsusr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'
```

**Okay, I found a fix.**

I just removed all the unnecessary gems using

```
for i in `gem list --no-versions`; do gem uninstall -aIx $i; done
```

Then, I just reinstalled rspec using `gem install rspec` which gave me rspec 3.0 and fixed all the problems. But, i get the deprecation warnings again.

Please tell me why the error occurred. The tutorial author said that it should work with rspec 2.10.0 or higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The tutorial author said that it should work with rspec 2.10.0 or higher.

Likely the author meant 2.10 or higher, within the 2.x range. RSpec 3.x has breaking changes.

Try uninstalling the gems like you did before, then this:

```
gem install rspec '>=2.10', '<3'
```

Then run your code.

The deprecation warnings that happen when you use RSpec 3 are not bad; they are coaching to tell you that the RSpec methods that you are calling are going to be phased out. These kinds of warnings are typical and fine when moving an entire version number e.g. 2.x to 3.x.

The errors you get when you use RSpec 2.0 are because that's a very old version, and the method you're calling didn't exist in 2.0. This is probably why the tutorial author said to use 2.10 or higher.

Most likely the tutorial is out of date, so the best solution is to wrote the tutorial author and let him/her know to update it.

If you're curious about how RSpec does its version numbers, here's a link to [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/).

Comment: Thanks. But, how do I find out why the error is happening ? I only guessed that changing the gem versions would help, but i had no solid reasoning for that.

Comment: I added more info for you to the answer, to explain why the error is happening, most likely.